# what Amazon AMI Linux to run Drupal?

Tags: drupal, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I am going to give amazon EC2 a try by moving my drupal site to it. At present the site is on a VPS running Ubuntu 10.04 and served through nginx+fastcgi.

Regarding that there are literally thousends of Amazon Machine Images (AMI) , I am wondering which suits the best for my need? After a brief research I found a pretty good general tutorial [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2008/09/13/running-drupal-website-amazon-ec2), however a bit dated, that suggests RightScale. Also [chapterthree](http://www.chapterthree.com/blog/zack_rosen/announcing_project_pantheon_amazon_ec2_ami_packages_drupal) offers a customized image, but I am not sure what is the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AMI's are kinda outdated now, but if you follow [these instructions from the pantheon group on g.d.o](http://groups.drupal.org/node/70268) using one of the Alestic Ubuntu 10.4 ami's as a base you should be fine to roll your own.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still looking for a Drupal AMI, you may want to check out [the ones at BitNami](http://bitnami.org/stack/drupal#cloudImage). We keep them up-to-date, and they are eligible for Amazon's free tier.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out https://www.getpantheon.com/. They are still in beta however.

Comment: After registration, I couldn't see how to get ami from pantheon. Apprently it need and invitation.

Comment: As I said, they are still in beta.

Answer (score 0):

if you search for pantheon or mercury in the public AMI's, you'll find the 1.0 and 1.1 beta. it should install the stack for you. I did it today and it seems really fast (although it still may be buggy because it's in beta). It's also a little daunting to have to do so much via command line (for me).